# Copying files from remote desktop to C: drive

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, citrix

I have to get a file from school that's saved on one of my college's computers. These computers have their desktops and stuff running on [Citrix](http://www.citrix.com/lang/English/home.asp). I know how to access the desktop, but for some reason I can't activate my wireless internet connection (or any other internet connection), nor is my USB accessible from the remote desktop running on my laptop. (Or at least I think it's what's called a remote desktop, the page from where I access this *thing* says: "*web interface for MetaFrame Presentation*")

The laptop is fine, **Windows 7**, *intel Core2 Duo* 2 GHz pr. core (not much, but hey, it's a work laptop) and just 2 GB RAM but it's fine for working.

Is there some way this *PowerPoint* file can be "dragged" from the remote [Citrix](http://www.citrix.com/lang/English/home.asp) desktop for **windows** to my internal [HDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive)?

### Just to clarify...

I am accessing the remote desktop through [this website](https://citrix.aaks.dk/Citrix/MetaFrame/auth/login.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to remotely access your school desktop, and uploading the file to [YouSendIt](https://www.yousendit.com/) and have it sent to an email address which you can access from your work laptop.  Then you simply download the file to your laptop.

Comment: I can't get any internet connections to run! This never happened before, this is the first time I use Citrix in Windows 7

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by not being able to run any internet connections?

Comment: Uhm... I am having a hard time explaining this, but basically there's no "wireless icon" and no "cable internet connection icon" in the little toolbar thing (right bottom corner) and I think the administrator disabled a lot of the network settings (in the control panel)

Comment: And this is on your work laptop?

Comment: yes - but nevermind, I somehow fixed it! Just clicked random stuff until it suddenly worked :)

Comment: Ok, so you are now able to access your school Citrix desktop from your work laptop?

Comment: Exactly, fixed by going nuts on my mouse :)

Comment: Great! Happy trails.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you access this remote desktop the same as any other remote desktop, you just need to go into the properties of the connection before initiating it and allow the session to have access to your local resources, it will then show up as an available drive.  You need to specify each drive seperately with a check mark.

Comment: check my upcoming update :)

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it! Just clicked random buttons and stuff until it suddenly worked!